# How can I split a document into a tree in Python?

Tags: python, nlp

So I have some rudimentary code going:

```
text='''Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Vivamus sit     amet sapien velit, ac sodales   
 ante. Integer mattis eros non turpis interdum et auctor enim consectetur, etc.

Praesent molestie suscipit bibendum. Donec justo purus, venenatis eget convallis sed, feugiat    
 vitae velit,etc.'''

paras=text.split("\n")

class Node:
    def __init__(self, name, children=None):
        self.name=name
        self.children=children
    def getchildren(self):
        return self.children
    def addchild(self, name):
        self.children.append(name)

class Tree:
    def __init__(self):
        self.nodes=[]
    def nodes(self):
        return self.nodes
    def add_node(self,ID,parent=None):
        node=Node(ID)
        self.ID=node
        if parent is not None:
            self.parent.addchild(ID)
```

However, I have no idea how to actually use this to break the text into a tree. I want to break it down into paragraph and sentence level. Below the sentences I will have the nouns.

This is the first step in my attempted implementation of a fractal summarization algorithm.

Comment: You might want to read the [NLP book chapter 3 on tokenization and such](http://www.nltk.org/book/ch03.html) and [chapter 8](http://www.nltk.org/book/ch08.html) about parsing sentence structures.

Answer (score 0):

There are a couple ways to accomplish this.

You could use a list comprehension and some splits because your structure isn't too deeply nested. As an example:

```
nested_list = [[w.split(' ') for w in s.split('. ')] for s in paras]
```

This essentially gets you a "tree" by having a list of list of lists. While that is convenient, it isn't really all that robust either.

The way this problem is generally solved is using what are called "tokenizers", "lexors", and a "parse tree". I would recommend checking out [pyparsing](https://pyparsing.wikispaces.com/) which is a python library for constructing arbitrary grammars and creating parse trees from them.

Comment: I don't know if this would give me the hierarchical structure I'm looking for.

Answer (score 0):

I think the first step is to parse the paragraph. Then you can very easily put it into a tree. Also you said you want to put the nouns as children, which means you need to know which words are nouns. Unless and until you parse it, you will not be able to detect the Parts-of-Speech (POS) of the para.

You can use NLTK (is good for learning purpose), or better use Stanford coreNLP/Berekeley NLP parsers for that.

Once you get the parsed structure, it is pretty easy to build the tree.